# jquery what to use to assign array values to a div id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array that I am breaking up via `toString` in a previous function (func1) and then passing the values into my current function (func2). Inside func2 I need to take each of those values and assign each to the tail end of a div id like this `document.getElementById('mydiv_' + ids)` The resulting output should be `<div id="mydiv_123">`.

Right now in the func2, the ids are coming in as 123,456,789 which give me the output of `<div id="mydiv_123,456,789">`

Instead I want the output of:
`<div id="mydiv_123">`
`<div id="mydiv_456">`
`<div id="mydiv_789">`

Would I obtain this using `jquery.each` or some other method? Should I try and use it as a string or leave it as an array for this? What is the best approach?

```
**data.ids input:**
(3) […]
​
0: "123"
​
1: "546"
​
2: "789"
​
length: 3
```

**AJAX:**
function func1() {

```
   jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                action: 'brett',
            }
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data.html);
            console.log(data.cids);
            var cids = data.cids.toString();
            callD(cids);

        })
        .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            alert(error);
            server error
        })
}



function func2(ids) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var var1 = document.getElementById('list')
        jQuery.each(cids, function(key, value) {
            var parent = document.getElementById('mydiv_' + ids)
            console.log('res_' + ids);
            if (var1) {
                parent.classList.add('black');
            } else {
                console.log('uh-oh');
            }
        })

    }, 7000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just pass the array without converting it to a string, you can loop through it in your function. A short example:

```
jQuery.ajax({...})
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data.cids);
        // assuming data.cids = ["123","456","789"]
        callD(data.cids)
    })
    // ...
}

function callD(cids) {
    for(let id of cids) {
        var parent = document.getElementById('mydiv_' + id)
        console.log('res_' + id);
    }
}
```